# cordova-plugin-media lastest version what am i doing wrong

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, media

I can't get get cordova-plugin-media to function. I'm using the Android studio and the Android emulator for mac, this is my code. I've done an onclick in the index.html file, but nothing happens. I've added the code for the media plugin in the index.js file.
All the codrova files and the media plugin are installed and added.

index.js

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', 
this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

var my_media = null;
// Play audio
//
function playAudio(src) {
// Play the audio file at url
var my_media = new Media(src,
    // success callback
    function () {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function (err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
    }
);
// Play audio
my_media.play();
} 


},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

The index.html

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <span class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="img/grongoling.jpg"><h2>Gröngöling</h2>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-audio ui-
btn-icon-notext right" onclick="playAudio('sounds/grongoling.mp3');">
</a>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="img/kattuggla.jpg"><h2>Kattuggla</h2>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-audio ui-
btn-icon-notext right" 
onclick="playAudio('sounds/kattuggla.mp3');"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="img/korp.jpg"><h2>Korp</h2>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-audio ui-
btn-icon-notext right" 
onclick="playAudio('sounds/korp.mp3');"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="img/storrehackspett.jpg"><h2>Större 
Hackspett</h2>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-audio ui-
btn-icon-notext right" 
onclick="playAudio('sounds/storrehackspett.mp3');"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="img/tofsvipa.jpg"><h2>Tofsvipa</h2>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-audio ui-
btn-icon-notext right" 
onclick="playAudio('sounds/tofsvipa.mp3');"></a> 
            </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you please update your post to better explain your issue?

Comment: @VladimirGatara Any error on console while plugin invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to define the playAudio()-function outside the onDeviceReady()-function to make it globally accessible and to be able to call it directly from HTML.

Moreover you initiliaze the my_media variable outside of the function and the recreate it again with var inside the function. Think about creating a global variable my_media and set it in the function without var or create it everytime in the function.

Comment: Plugin code invocaion cannot happen outside device ready. So i guess that may not be valid